# Export vars env to tmux's window/session/pane's env

Tags: bash, shell, tmux, bashrc, subshell

Is there any way to export/upgrade list of variable env from a file or something to tmux's window/session/pane?

Here I have to manually source `.bashrc` to update new var env to each tmux's pane.

Answer (score 1):

#### Add ENV in ~/.tmux.conf file

Did you try declaring the ENV var in `~/.tmux.conf`

#### Example ~/.tmux.conf snipet

```bsh
FOO="BAR"
```

#### test

Reload tmux and echo $FOO